# Change the background color of text if a certain limit is crossed in React Mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have TextField from MUI. Now i want to change the background-color of input text change which is out of the limit.

Any Idea??

Comment: What have you tried? Are you able to store the current value of the field? Are you able to check if it's in range?

Comment: Yes i have tried.  I want to highlight only that text which exceeds the limit. For example If the limit is 5, I write "My name is Hamza". then only text "me is Hamza" to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You need state:

```
const [text, setText] = useState("")
```

You need to handle the state update:

```
const onChange = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()
setText(e.target.value)
}
```

Then with your TextField:

```
<TextField value={text} onChange={onChange} sx={{ backgroundColor: text.length > 10 ? "red" : "yellow" }} />
```

if the length of the text string is greater than 10, the background color will be red, otherwise it will be yellow. This is a shortcut I really reccomend handling your conditions in a separate function like 'handleTextBg()' or sth. For more options, you can use switch.

Comment: Good answer but i want to highlight only that text which exceeds the limit. For example

If the limit is 5, I write "My name is Hamza". then only text "me is Hamza" to be highlighted.